# Can't cast object to its own type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, razor-pages

In a Blazor page, I've got this weird bug when "casting" a model to it's actual given type. The error is this:

```
Unable to set property 'Model' on object of type 'CSBApp.ExtHdr'. 
The error was: [A]TQ.ModelExt cannot be cast to [B]TQ.ModelExt. 
Type A originates from 'TQ.Exts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' 
at location 'C:\_work\Server.SSB\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\TQ.Exts.dll'. 
Type B originates from 'TQ.Exts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' 
at location 'C:\_work\Server.SSB\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\TQ.Exts.dll'.
```

Seems like there are two identical assemblies loaded!

```
object Model = ...; // actually a ModelExt
var a1 = Model.GetType().Assembly;
var a2 = typeof(ModelExt).Assembly;
if (a1 != a2) {
    DBG.Log("merde...");
}
```

The assemblies, a1 & a2, have the same name, version & location but different m_assembly.

How is this possible??

Comment: Log the stack trace from an AppDomain.AssemblyLoad event?

Comment: Happens since dawn of time (as soon as ASP.Net was available) - since re-build does not restart the site but simply loads another assembly with the same name all objects that are related to the request - cached / stored in in-memory state now have mismatched type which look exactly identical...

Comment: @Alexei I'm not using IIS but an asp.net core standalone server. The server is restarted every time.

Comment: @Lakeman Yeah, it's loaded twice... Once from Assembly.LoadFile and later from  unrecognizable native code

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.  See here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading) about loading in multiple contexts.

In short, Use `Assembly.LoadFrom()` instead of `Assembly.LoadFile()`.

And thanks to Jeremy Lakeman for the AppDomain.AssemblyLoad event idea.